# Tables and Figures side-by-side in Knitr or RMarkdown Beamer

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, beamer

I am trying to create a Beamer Presentation slide in RMarkdown / Knitr . In the slide I would like to have a table and a figure placed Side-by-side , and then some more text underneath. I can only get as far as my attempt as shown in the code. I would like to have the density plot placed, next to the Hmisc Table.

I am not using Kable or xtable since I get more control over the tables with Hmisc.

Also, How can I adjust the text characteristics (font-size, type, color) in the individual slides?

````
---
title: "BeamerTest1"
subtitle: Beamer Subtitle
author: "Author"

output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: CambridgeUS
    colortheme: "beaver"
    fonttheme: "structurebold"
---

## Slide with Table, Figure and Text

My topic for this slide 

\scalebox{0.35}{
```{r hmisc-table, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(Hmisc)
latex(head(mtcars), file='', table.env=FALSE, center='none')
```
}


```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.show='hold', fig.height=1, fig.width=2.5}
library(ggplot2)
mt <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) + geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="#FF6666") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=10),axis.text.x  = element_text(size=8),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=10),axis.text.y  = element_text(size=8))
mt
```

- Here is some Bullet Text
- And some more
    - Subtext
    - More Subtext
````

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

As I've already answered [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20847371/10215301) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53956273/10215301), I repeat my answer in which I use `:::` notation, adding the codes to create the output you may want.

You can use [`fenced_divs`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#fenced-code-blocks) notation or `:::` to create columns or `Two Content layout'. See also [this page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004672913-Rendering-PowerPoint-presentations-with-RStudio#columns) to know more about the notation.

````
## Slide With Image Left

::: columns

:::: column
left
::::

:::: column
right

```{r your-chunk-name, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="your-caption-name"}
knitr::include_graphics("your/figure/path/to/the-image.pdf")

#The figure will appear on the right side of the slide...
```
::::

:::
````

Since `pandoc 2+`, which supports the notation, was implemented in `RStudio v1.2+`, you may need to install [`RStudio v1.2+`](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/) first. The installation is easy enough (at least in my case); just download and install `RStudio v1.2+`. In the way of installation, the former version of `RStudio` on your computer will be replaced with the new one without uninstalling it manually.

The following figure is an example which you have if you implement the notation.

[image]

The MWE code which produced the slide above is here, too:

````
---
title: "BeamerTest1"
subtitle: Beamer Subtitle
author: "Author"

output:
  beamer_presentation:
  theme: CambridgeUS
  colortheme: "beaver"
  fonttheme: "structurebold"
---

## Slide with Table, Figure and Text

::: columns

:::: column

My topic for this slide 

\scalebox{0.35}{
```{r hmisc-table, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(Hmisc)
latex(head(mtcars), file='', table.env=FALSE, center='none')
```
}


```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.show='hold', fig.height=1, fig.width=2.5}
library(ggplot2)
mt <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) + geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="#FF6666") +
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=10),axis.text.x  = element_text(size=8),
axis.title.y = element_text(size=10),axis.text.y  = element_text(size=8))
mt
```

::::

:::: column

- Here is some Bullet Text
- And some more
    - Subtext
    - More Subtext

::::

:::
````

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is not more upvoted. It's the most general one and really solves it neatly.

Comment: This approach is indeed very neat. As per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52140091/10451245), more than 2 columns are feasible. Interestingly the alignment of the content in the columns switches from top-alignment o center-alignment.

Comment: Posed a question regarding [how to adjust the vertical alignment in this approach for multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66313282/vertically-center-align-content-of-columns-in-a-beamer-presentation-generated-wi).

Answer (score 4):

There have been [issue](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/202717656-Can-we-have-columns-in-rmarkdown-beamer-presentations-) having two column layout in beamer presentation. But in the same post there is workaround:

In short: Error is related to pandoc conversion engine, which treats everything between `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}` as **TeX**. It can be avoided by giving new definition for `begin{column}` and `end{column}` in yaml header.

Create mystyle.tex and write there:

```
\def\begincols{\begin{columns}}
\def\begincol{\begin{column}}
\def\endcol{\end{column}}
\def\endcols{\end{columns}}
```

> In the Rmd file use these new **definitions**

````
---
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    includes:
      in_header: mystyle.tex
---


Two Column Layout 
-------

\begincols
  \begincol{.48\textwidth}

This slide has two columns.

  \endcol
\begincol{.48\textwidth}

```{r}
#No error here i can run any r code
plot(cars)
```

  \endcol
\endcols
````

And you get:

[image]

Comment: It works but after you use the `\begincols` ones you have to used it for the rest of the slides (overthought you just need one column) do you know a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a two column layout, like you would have to do if you were doing this directly in Beamer. See for example:

- [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847371/two-column-layouts-in-rstudio-presentations-slidify-pandoc) on doing this with the tools available with RStudio. (Please note that this is one area where RStudio and the RMarkdown package have evolved a lot recently and the question is somewhat dated, but it does hint at the features now available.)
- [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142134/slides-with-columns-in-pandoc) for a solution with inline LaTeX and Pandoc. (This will also work with RStudio as the newer releases use a bundled copy of pandoc as the Markdown engine.)
- [this post on the pandoc mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.text.pandoc/11734) discussing how to include Markdown inside of your LaTeX blocks, e.g. the Beamer commands/environments for columns.
- [this question on TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83361/two-column-layout-with-text-and-knitr-chunk) could help you, but you would need to adapt it a bit for RMarkdown (the question uses the Sweave-style syntax for embedding R into LaTeX with knitr).

The basic idea for your problem would be a two-column layout for the upper portion of the slide, and a one-column layout for the bottom. You then put the individual R code blocks into their own column. (You may need to play with vertical spacing if the two figures differ in size.)

The Rpres format is all-or-nothing on column layouts for a given slide (at least last time I checked), so that solution would be less than ideal when you want the bottom part of the slide to be a single 'column'.

Another solution would be combining the two figures into one and then displaying the merged figure. I'm not sure how you would do with a table and a graphic, but for two graphics, you could use the `gridExtra` package to place two `lattice` or `ggplot2` (or even an unholy mixture of both) next to each other in a single `grid` and thus in a single, combined figure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set the chunk option `fig.align=right` as described [here](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/)

Comment: Thanks Jthorpe, but that does not solve the problem. It does move the figure to the right but it is still a _level below_ the table, no matter how much I resize either the figure or table.

Comment: Perhaps the answer at the bottom of [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83361/two-column-layout-with-text-and-knitr-chunk) page will help.