# How to place *multiple* code chunks side by side in Quarto -> HTML?

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, quarto

How can I place *multiple* code chunks side-by-side in Quarto -> HTML?
I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73170958/6105259), which is great, but it accounts for just 2 code chunks. Is there a way to place up to 4-5 code chunks side-by-side, possibly using [`.column-screen-inset`](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/article-layout.html#screen-inset), to take advantage of the entire screen width?

I know a way to get exactly what I want, but it has two caveats (which are essentially one):

1. It works for ***images***
2. It relies on `knitr::include_graphics()`

Thus, if I do:

**my_file.qmd**

````
---
title: "quarto-page-side-by-side"
---

```{r}
#| eval: true
#| echo: false
#| layout-ncol: 4
#| column: screen-inset

knitr::include_graphics("media/a.jpg")
knitr::include_graphics("media/b.jpg")
knitr::include_graphics("media/c.jpg")
knitr::include_graphics("media/d.jpg")
```
````

I get [this nice page layout](https://tubular-cupcake-218b01.netlify.app/) with 4 images, side-by-side, that get resized as I change the window size. What's more, if we keep narrowing the window, ultimately the images will be stacked one on top of the other.

Is there a way to achieve this functionality or similar, but with code chunks instead of images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this using some CSS.

````
---
title: "quarto-page-side-by-side"
---

```{css, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE}
.multiple .column {
  width: 15%;
  margin: 5px;
}

.multiple .columns {
  display: flex;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .multiple .column {
    width: auto;
  }

 .multiple .columns {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

::::: { .multiple}

:::: {.columns .column-screen-inset}

::: column
```{r}
print("This is the 1st code chunk")
```
:::

::: column
```{r}
print("This is the 2nd code chunk")
```
:::

::: column
```{r}
print("This is the 3rd code chunk")
```
:::

::: column
```{r}
print("This is the 4th code chunk")
```
:::

::: column
```{r}
print("This is the 5th code chunk")
```
:::

::::
:::::
````

---

[image: five code chunks placed side by side]

---

If you want to add more chunks side by side, just decrease the value of the `width` property within the `.multiple .column` selector.

Comment: Looks awesome, many thanks! Is it also possible to implement the one-of-top-of-the-other when the window gets *very* narrow, as in my [images example](https://tubular-cupcake-218b01.netlify.app/)? So it would fit mobile screens nicely.

Comment: See the edit in the CSS code chunk.